# Difference between Html.ActionLink and Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC. Can anyone explain difference between Html.ActionLink and Ajax.ActionLink?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically both work perfectlly. The main difference between these is-

**Html.ActionLink**- Html.ActionLink create a new link on the view and, and when user click on the link, it does not link to the view directly , it will go through the MVC routing . It will map to a action method by routing.

```
Html.ActionLink(test.login, 
                "Action",   //  ActionMethod Name
                "Login",  // Controller Name.
                new { person.loginId}, //  Route arguments.
                null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. You need this value
                      //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
                      //     (refer to comments, below).
                )
```

**Ajax.ActionLink**:Ajax.ActionLink also create a new link on the view but when the user clicks it  Ajax.ActionLink sends the asynchronous request instead of navigating to the new URL. With the Ajax.ActionLink we specify what controller's action method is to be invoked and also specify what to do with the response coming back from the action method.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Customer from Germany", // <-- Text to display
                 "Germany", // <-- Action Method Name
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {
                     UpdateTargetId="CustomerList", // <-- DOM element ID to update
                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
                     HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method
                 })
```

Hope it will help you out. **For more understanding go through this** [**Article**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)